# How to validate HTML input filed using HTML5

Tags: html

I have to validate input text field as a phone number field. To do that I'am going to use HTML5 validation.

I already wrote code like this:

```
<input maxlength="8" type="text" name="phone" required />
```

I used **required** to validate this form. **But how to validate this for
Enter only digits and  8 digits.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input maxlength="8" pattern="\d{8}" type="tel" name="phone" required />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern.

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{8}" />
```

`\d` is the regular expression for a number.

Comment: Only correct answer here... would like to suggest you that you can also use `type="number"` for better semantic meaning as anyways you are using `pattern` to validate

Comment: @Mr.Alien any reason for using `type="number"` as opposed to `type="tel"` which is semantically specific to phone numbers?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Oh I missed the phone word, just went with number as written here *Enter only digits and 8 digits*

Comment: This allows any number of digits, not 8, as requested.

Comment: Suggesting `type="number"` for a telephone number is wrong, and it violates the recommendation of the very drafts that define `type="number"` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Type="tel" but this not validates everything. You can use the pattern attribute with an regex.

The input-patter [support](http://html5pattern.com/):

Pattern Support Firefox 4+ & Chrome 5+ & Opera 9.6+ & MSIE 10+

For example:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*([-]?[0-9]+)*" >
```

For the 8 diggets you can use the maxlength="8"